# Radar lines do not appear in visual interface when using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

When coding a set of radar(s) that originates from a given sprite, the code appears to work and the demo visual loads properly, but the radars themselves do not appear on the visual interface. How can I recode it so that the radars do appear on-screen, originating from the sprite?

sprite.py:

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
from tilemap import *
import math
vec = pg.math.Vector2
show_debug = True
SCREEN = pg.surface.Surface((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

def collide_with_walls(sprite, group, dir):
    if dir == 'x':
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, sprite.collide_hit_rect)
        if hits:
            if sprite.vel.x > 0:
                sprite.pos.x = hits[0].rect.left - sprite.hit_rect.width / 2
            if sprite.vel.x < 0:
                sprite.pos.x = hits[0].rect.right + sprite.hit_rect.width / 2
                sprite.vel.x = 0
            sprite.hit_rect.centerx = sprite.pos.x
    if dir == 'y':
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, sprite.collide_hit_rect)
        if hits:
            if sprite.vel.y > 0:
                sprite.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top - sprite.hit_rect.height / 2
            if sprite.vel.y < 0:
                sprite.pos.y = hits[0].rect.bottom + sprite.hit_rect.height / 2
            sprite.vel.y = 0
            sprite.hit_rect.centery = sprite.pos.y

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = game.player_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.hit_rect = PLAYER_HIT_RECT
        self.hit_rect.center = self.rect.center
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.pos = vec(x, y) * TILESIZE
        self.rot = 0
        self.angle = 0
        self.radars = []

    def get_keys(self):
        self.rot_speed = 0
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.vx, self.vy = 0, 0
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT] or keys[pg.K_a]:
            self.rot_speed = PLAYER_ROT_SPEED
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT] or keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.rot_speed = -PLAYER_ROT_SPEED
        if keys[pg.K_UP] or keys[pg.K_w]:
            self.vel = vec(PLAYER_SPEED, 0).rotate(-self.rot)
        if keys[pg.K_DOWN] or keys[pg.K_s]:
            self.vel = vec(-PLAYER_SPEED / 2, 0).rotate(-self.rot)

    def collide_hit_rect(one, two):
        return one.hit_rect.colliderect(two.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.get_keys()
        self.rot = (self.rot + self.rot_speed * self.game.dt) % 360
        self.image = pg.transform.rotate(self.game.player_img, self.rot)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        self.pos += self.vel * self.game.dt
        self.hit_rect.centerx = self.pos.x
        collide_with_walls(self, self.game.walls, 'x')
        self.hit_rect.centery = self.pos.y
        collide_with_walls(self, self.game.walls, 'y')
        self.rect.center = self.hit_rect.center
        self.radars.clear()
        for radar_angle in (-60, -30, 0, 30, 60):
            self.radar(radar_angle)

    def radar(self, radar_angle):
        length = 0
        x = int(self.rect.center[0])
        y = int(self.rect.center[1])
        try:
            while not SCREEN.get_at((x, y)) == pg.Color(2, 105, 31, 255) and length < 200:
                length += 1
                x = int(self.rect.center[0] +
                        math.cos(math.radians(self.angle + radar_angle)) * length)
                y = int(self.rect.center[1] -
                        math.sin(math.radians(self.angle + radar_angle)) * length)
                
        except IndexError:
            pass

            if show_debug:
                pg.draw.line(SCREEN, (225, 225, 225, 225), self.rect.center,
                                 (x, y), 1)
                pg.draw.circle(SCREEN, (0, 225, 0, 0), (x, y), 3)

            dist = int(
                math.sqrt(
                    math.pow(self.rect.center[0] - x, 2) +
                    math.pow(self.rect.center[1] - y, 2)))

            self.radars.append([radar_angle, dist])
```

tilemap.py:

```
import pygame as pg
import pytmx
from settings import *

def collide_hit_rect(one, two):
    return one.hit_rect.colliderect(two.rect)

class Map:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.data = []
        with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
            for line in f:
                self.data.append(line.strip())

        self.tilewidth = len(self.data[0])
        self.tileheight = len(self.data)
        self.width = self.tilewidth * TILESIZE
        self.height = self.tileheight * TILESIZE

class TiledMap:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        tm = pytmx.load_pygame(filename, pixelalpha=True)
        self.width = tm.width * tm.tilewidth
        self.height = tm.height * tm.tileheight
        self.tmxdata = tm

    def render(self, surface):
        ti = self.tmxdata.get_tile_image_by_gid
        for layer in self.tmxdata.visible_layers:
            if isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledTileLayer):
                for x, y, gid, in layer:
                    tile = ti(gid)
                    if tile:
                        surface.blit(tile, (x * self.tmxdata.tilewidth,
                                            y * self.tmxdata.tileheight))

    def make_map(self):
        temp_surface = pg.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.render(temp_surface)
        return temp_surface

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.camera = pg.Rect(0, 0, width, height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def apply(self, entity):
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def apply_rect(self, rect):
        return rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        x = -target.rect.centerx + int(WIDTH / 2)
        y = -target.rect.centery + int(HEIGHT / 2)

        # limit scrolling to map size
        x = min(0, x)  # left
        y = min(0, y)  # top
        x = max(-(self.width - WIDTH), x)  # right
        y = max(-(self.height - HEIGHT), y)  # bottom
        self.camera = pg.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)
```

settings.py:

```
import pygame as pg

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
DARKGREY = (40, 40, 40)
LIGHTGREY = (100, 100, 100)
GREEN = (67, 163, 75)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
DARKTEAL = (59, 173, 154)
BLUE = (16, 87, 201)
BLUE2 = (16, 87, 225)

# game settings
WIDTH = 1024   # 16 * 64 or 32 * 32 or 64 * 16
HEIGHT = 768  # 16 * 48 or 32 * 24 or 64 * 12
FPS = 60
TITLE = "Tilemap Demo"
BGCOLOR = BLUE

TILESIZE = 16
GRIDWIDTH = WIDTH / TILESIZE
GRIDHEIGHT = HEIGHT / TILESIZE


#Player settings
PLAYER_SPEED = 100
PLAYER_IMG = 'Fletcher-class DD.png'
PLAYER_ROT_SPEED = 50
PLAYER_HIT_RECT = pg.Rect(0, 0, 35, 35)
```

My guess is that the problem lies with `SCREEN = pg.surface.Surface((WIDTH, HEIGHT))` in sprite.py, my I'm not sure as to how to fix it.

Comment: 1. Where is the `radar` method of the `Player` object called? Since the lines are drawn in this method, it is necessary to know where it is called. It should be called after clearing the display and before updating the display. 2. you have a `Camera`. Are the lines drawn in relation to the camera? 3. Please consider [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

In Pygame, everything is drawn to a [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) object associated with the display. In your example this is `SCREEN`. If you draw on the *Surface* associated to the PyGame display, this is not immediately visible in the display. The changes become visible, when the display is updated with either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip). Usually, the entire scene is redrawn in each frame. At the beginning of the frame, the display is cleared or the background is drawn. This makes everything gone that was drawn before. At the end of the frame the display is updated. Therefore, anything that is not drawn after the display is cleared and before the display is updated is not visible in the scene.